# What format to use to add new static pages in sub folders in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My website has two static pages and I need two other pages but in sub folders.
Under views I have a folder static_pages and  the current about page route is

```
get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
```

I have created a sub folder under static_pages with the name: "es" which will include the about page in Spanish.
How can I write the route for this?

```
get 'es/about', to: 'static_pages/es#about'
```

does not seem to work.

And what empty method to add to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ActionView::PartialRenderer#render`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#method-i-render) method and pass the file you want to use:

```
def es_about
  render 'static_pages/es/about'
end
```

Where about is under the es folder which at the same time is under static_pages folder:

```
app/views/static_pages
├── about.html.erb
└── es
    └── about.html.erb
```

The route should specify the route, the controller and the action:

```
get 'es/about', to: 'static_pages#es_about'
```

This would work the same way for any route or specific file you want to use, but if you're thinking on adding localized routes, then you can take a look to the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a general form using this method:

config/routes.rb

```
get 'static_pages/:first/:second' => 'pages#show'
```

Then in your PagesController

```
def show
    render "/static_pages/#{params[:first]}/#{params[:second]}"
end
```

Then in your views it will render any static page in the first two levels of folders within the static_pages folder. You can add as many levels as you like with the same format. With this method you don't need to make a specific route for each view, just put them in any sub_folder you like within the root folder specified (e.g. static_pages).